# C++ : data file has error: Expected unqualified-id

Tags: c++

**SIMPLY PUT** Why does my text data file `myData.cpp` get the error `Expected unqualified-id before '{' token`? The file alone gives rise to this error and has been reproduced here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f32b5e643fb4d52

```
// ***** myData.cpp ******
{ // <---- error occurs here
    { "*****", "Error" },
    { "00-01", "Instructional exposition (textbooks, tutorial papers, etc.)" },
    { "00-02", "Research exposition (monographs, survey articles)" },
    { "00A05", "General mathematics" }
}
```

**MORE DETAIL. Potentially helpful, but not necessary to reproduce error.**

Right now, with 2 files `main.cpp` and `myFunctions.cpp`, everything works. But when I split it into 3 files `main.cpp`, `myFunctions.cpp`, and `myData.cpp`, I get the error `Expected unqualified-id before '{' token`.

I want to make it 3 files, because the text data for `myData.cpp` is pretty long and I don't want it to clutter `myFunctions.cpp`.

This is what I have as 2 files that compiles.

```
// ***** main.cpp *****
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern size_t msc_get_no(const char*);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    assert(argc >= 0);
    return (int)msc_get_no(argv[1]);
}


// ****** myFunctions.cpp *****
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

extern size_t msc_get_no(const char*);

struct msc_data
{
   const char* code;
   const char* desc;
};

typedef struct msc_data MSCDat;

static const MSCDat mscdat[] =
{
    { "*****", "Error" },
    { "00-01", "Instructional exposition (textbooks, tutorial papers, etc.)" },
    { "00-02", "Research exposition (monographs, survey articles)" },
    { "00A05", "General mathematics" }
}
   ;

static const size_t msccnt = sizeof(mscdat) / sizeof(mscdat[0]);

static int msc_cmp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
   const char*   msc_code = static_cast<const char*>(a);
   const MSCDat* p        = static_cast<const MSCDat*>(b);
   return strcmp(msc_code, p->code);
}

size_t msc_get_no(const char* msc_code)
{
   MSCDat* p;
   p = (MSCDat*) bsearch(msc_code, &mscdat[0], msccnt, sizeof(mscdat[0]), msc_cmp);
   return p - &mscdat[0];
}
```

This is what I have as 3 files that does not compile, because of the `Expected unqualified-id` error in `myData.cpp`. The only difference is with `myFunctions.cpp`, so I have excluded `main.cpp` and `myData.cpp`.

```
// ***** myFunctions.cpp ***** 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

extern size_t msc_get_no(const char*);

struct msc_data
{
   const char* code;
   const char* desc;
};

typedef struct msc_data MSCDat;

static const MSCDat mscdat[] =
#include "myData.cpp" //<------ only here is different
   ;

static const size_t msccnt = sizeof(mscdat) / sizeof(mscdat[0]);

static int msc_cmp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
   const char*   msc_code = static_cast<const char*>(a);
   const MSCDat* p        = static_cast<const MSCDat*>(b);
   return strcmp(msc_code, p->code);
}

size_t msc_get_no(const char* msc_code)
{
   MSCDat* p;
   p = (MSCDat*) bsearch(msc_code, &mscdat[0], msccnt, sizeof(mscdat[0]), msc_cmp);
   return p - &mscdat[0];
}
```

**THANK YOU**

Comment: Your compiler may be attempting to compile `myData.cpp` on its own. Try naming it something like `myData.inl`, or instructing your compiler to exclude it from the build.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C and C++ : data file with error "Expected unqualified-id"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49619851/c-and-c-data-file-with-error-expected-unqualified-id)

Comment: `#including` an implementation file is a very bad design practice, expecially in C++. Make it a seperate compilation unit and use appropriate headers. Anything else is just a mess and will fall on your head eventually. If this is for your job or a course, your senior or tutor should have a serious talk to you, too.

Comment: @Olaf I have seen them used for [X-Macros](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Preprocessor_directives_and_macros#X-Macros) in the past, which isn't necessarily that awful when used judiciously.

Comment: @Olaf thanks for your comment. The file was actually for C originally, but I'm converting it to use for C++, so some of the design practices (whether good or bad, I'm not sure) are carrying over. What do you mean by separate compilation unit? And what about `#including` is making it bad design practice? Thanks.

Comment: It is not about coding _style_, but semantics. What about "`#include`ing an implementation file … " don't you understand? I don't see how it can be expresseds any more clear. If you have a reasonable senior or tutor, he should tell you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IDE tries to compile `myData.cpp` by itself. But this file is only an include file. If you rename it to `myData.h` (or even 
`myData.dat`) everthing should be fine.

Comment: Wonderful, that worked! What a simple solution. Thank you! (`.hpp` worked for me, I didn't try `.dat`)